# Can some SQL updates be guaranteed to always work, thus avoiding having to handle exceptions and retry?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can some SQL updates be guaranteed to always work, such as the T-SQL statement below, so that you do not need to add code to catch exceptions and retry?

```
update exampleTable set exampleField = exampleField + 1
output inserted.exampleField
where Id = 1
```

where exampleTable has these fields:

1. Id (int, primary key)
2. exampleField (int)
3. Timestamp

The conditions for the above are:

- you can assume the database is always up
- assume the connection is always good
- there are no other routines that update or insert records in this table, i.e. the only changes are from the statement above.

Comment: Someone inadvertently dropped your table?

Comment: in normal case, I don't see any potentially failure, but if you saying catch exception and retry, what kind of exception you caught ?

Comment: The only way this statement would run into an exception is if this table has a trigger on it that do some validation on that exampleField. Assuming the conditions and the table you show. Other than that it is just impossible.

Comment: Is exampleField nullable?  If it is null to begin with, then adding 1 will still get your null.

Comment: What can go wrong?  Let me count the ways... overlong transaction lock is possible, ignoring the things you already mentioned.  Also, you'll need to put the initial record in there some how (otherwise you get a _warning_, when this runs).  I'm a little concerned about this - what are you trying to do?